# FCM notification like instagram

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented FCM in my app and getting notification from the action performed in the app. So if a user likes a post I get a notification like "Someone(name) likes you. if multiple users like the post I get multiple notification exes: User1 likes you, User2 likes you.

I want one notification where it shows the Username of the user + number of other user liked you. How to handle this on client side or do we have to handle it from server side. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Firebase cloud messaging will let you send messages to your users in real time. I suggest you read about it from the official google documentation, then implement it so that when someone likes your post, your server is able to send a JSON message to activate Firebase Cloud Messaging.

There are two forms of notification:

- Notification messages, sometimes thought of as “display messages.”
  These are handled by the FCM (firebase cloud messaging) SDK
  automatically.
- Data messages, which are handled by the client app.

**Step one:** Add the FCM SDK API to your project
[image]

**Step two** Create a service that can receive your data message

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
   private static final String TAG = "myTag";
   @Override
   public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
 Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
 Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}
```

**Step three:** Create your notification from that service

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("Someone liked your post")
    .setContentText("Accept this answer if it is useful!");
```

**Step four:** Handle any "likes" on your server side by sending a JSON request to your Android app with the notification:

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...", //this specefies the device
    "notification":{
      "title":"Someone liked your post",
      "body":"col"
    }
"data": {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
 "android":{
       "ttl":"86400s",
       "notification"{
         "click_action":"OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"
       }
     },
  }
}
```

More about Firebase Cloud Messaging on my [blog](https://themillibit.wordpress.com/2017/11/19/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial/).

Comment: I am getting notifications properly but one notification for one action performed and I want one notification for multiple actions performed exes: 20 people liked so the notification would be: someone + 19 others liked you.

Comment: What about image?